# How to select rows with the highest column value and in case of duplicates return the top most row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `player_ratings` which contains two columns: `player_id` and `rating`. For example:

```
 |  player_id     |       rating       | 
 |     1          |        950         |
 |     1          |        945         |
 |     2          |        850         |
 |     2          |        850         |
```

I want to return a list of players with the highest player_rating.

If there are duplicate rows in the table, return the topmost row. For example, `player_id` 2 has two rows with the same `rating` so return row 3 in the table.

the list shouldn't contain any duplicate players. (see the expected output)

I tried the following query but it doesn't remove duplicates rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM player_ratings 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT player_id, MAX(rating) as max_rating FROM player_ratings GROUP BY player_id) topratings 
 ON player_ratings.player_id = topratings.player_id
 AND player_ratings.rating = topratings.max_rating 
ORDER BY player_ratings.rating DESC ;
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

```
 |  player_id     |       ranking       | 
 |     1          |         950         |
 |     2          |         850         |
 |     2          |         850         |
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
 |  player_id     |       ranking       | 
 |     1          |         950         |
 |     2          |         850         |
```

Comment: just use distinct

Comment: which version of mysql do you have?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a "top-most" row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's just about two columns, the player ID and the ranking, you can simply aggregate:

```
select player_id, max(rating)
from player_ratings
group by player_id
order by max(rating) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
   SELECT player_id, MAX(rating) as max_rating FROM player_ratings 
   GROUP BY player_id
   order by max_rating desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a unique id in `player_ratings`, then you can do:

```
select pr.*
from player_ratings pr
where pr.player_ratings_id in (select pr2.player_ratings_id
                               from player_ratings pr2
                               where pr2.player_id = pr.player_id
                               order by pr2.max_rating desc, 
                                        pr2.player_ratings_id asc
                              );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`

```
SELECT player_id, MAX(rating) as Rating
FROM player_ratings GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```